# Accidentally turned on line spacing in Eclipse. How to turn off?

Tags: eclipse, macos, google-chrome, firefox, spacing

Out of nowhere, this line spacing happened. This is not normal. I must have hit some weird key combination on accident. How do I turn it off? I'm on Mac OS X 10.9.5 and Eclipse Standard/SDK Version: Kepler Service Release 2. Here's an example of what it looks like:

[image]

I tried googling it and can't find any answers. I only get results about how to change line spacing in specific programs, but this seems to have affected my whole computer.

**Google Chrome: (Normally, the google results are not spaced out that much)**

[image]

**Firefox: (It's not just a google chrome problem):**

[image]

**How do I get it back to normal line spacing?** Thanks!

Comment: Entering some Unicode characters (such as Chinese) can cause the line spacing in Eclipse to increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just restarted my computer and that fixed it. Google chrome and firefox look the same, so I guess their line spacing was normal to begin with. Eclipse looks like this now, which is much better!

[image]

I'm still curious if anyone finds a better way to turn off line spacing besides restarting the whole computer. I'm also curious how line spacing got turned on.